# How To have MYSQL only show results that have been modified in the last 11 seconds

Tags: mysql, time

Is there a simple and efficient way to make this query only return results that have been modified or created in the last 10 seconds.
Here is the query.

`SELECT msg.sender, msg.GameName, msg.ModTime FROM msg
WHERE msg.sender ='".$sender."' ORDER BY msg.sender ASC`

Comment: date_sub() function is the answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ModTime is storing both create and modified date your query will look like this;

```
SELECT msg.sender, msg.GameName, msg.ModTime FROM msg
WHERE msg.sender ='".$sender."' AND
msg.ModTime >= DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 10 second )
ORDER BY msg.sender ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something along the lines of `msg.ModTime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 SECOND)` to your `WHERE` clause.